# How to output most common vowel

Tags: python, string

I have managed to code this :

```
def vowels(s) :
    result = 0
    n = 0
    while n<len(s):
        if s[n] in "AEIOUaeiou" : result = result+1
        n = n+1
    return result

line = input("Type a line of text: ")
print("The line contains", vowels(line), "vowels")
```

which gives me how many vowels in total are in line.. 
But i want to know how to change it so it will output
the vowel(s) which occurred most frequently and how many times it occured

Comment: def vowels(s) :
    result = 0
    n = 0
    while n<len(s):
        if s[n] in "AEIOUaeiou" : result = result+1
        n = n+1
    return result

line = input("Type a line of text: ")
print("The line contains", vowels(line), "vowels")

Comment: ``collections.Counter(letter for letter in s if letter in 'AEIOUaeiou').most_common()``

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to get the count of occurrence of each vowel in the text.

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> def vowels(s):
...     return Counter(c for c in s if c in "AEIOUaeiou")

>>> counter = vowels("Lorem ipsum lorem")
>>> print counter
Counter({'e': 2, 'o': 2, 'i': 1, 'u': 1})
>>> print sum(counter.values())
6
>>> print counter.most_common()
[('e', 2), ('o', 2), ('i', 1), ('u', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `collections.Counter` and its `most_common` method

```
from collections import Counter

def vowels(s) :
    vow_found = [i for i in s.lower() if i in 'aeiou']
    c = Counter(vow_found)
    return len(vow_found), c.most_common()

line = input("Type a line of text: ")
numvow, most_com = vowels(line)
print("The line contains", numvow, "vowels")
print("and the most common are", most_com)
```

which, with an input of

```
hello I am your friend today
```

produces

```
The line contains 10 vowels
and the most common are [('o', 3), ('i', 2), ('a', 2), ('e', 2), ('u', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)to do this:

```
import collections

vowels = lambda s: collections.Counter(i for i in s if i in 'AEIOUaeiou').most_common(1)[0]

line = input("Type a line of text: ")
v = vowels(line)

print("The most frequently vowel is", v[0], 'the times is', v[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

What my approach does:

- Using `lower()` to make the input lowercase.
- count the frequency of each vowel in the input and the store in a list.
- Reversely sort the list, so that the largest frequency comes first.
- Pick the first element of sorted list.

Hope this helps:

```
line = input("Type a line of text: ").lower()
print(sorted([(i,line.count(i)) for i in "aeiou"], key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowels(s) :
    vowel_letters = "AEIOUaeiou"
    result = []
    for vowel in vowel_letters:
        result.append((vowel,s.count(vowel)))
    result.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    return result[-1]

line = raw_input("Type a line of text: ")
print vowels(line)
```

Comment: A bit of commentary would prevent your answers from getting flagged as too short.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter simpler code for the same

```
from collections import Counter
def most_common_vowel(input_string):
    return Counter(
            filter(lambda x: x in "aeiou", input_string.lower())
        ).most_common(1)
```

Use `filter` function to remove non-vowels from string and the use `Counter` to get most common element

Comment: `E` and `e` would have separate frequency. I did the same thing initially, but I think it makes sense to merge them independently of lower/uppercase